# Same odds ratio for both rows and columns

Tags: self-study, spss, odds-ratio

I'm getting stuck on how to run the odds ratio test for these two different questions:

1. Novice clinicians are more likely to use validated assessments than other assessments
2. Novice clinicians are more likely to use validated assessments than other clinicians.

I thought it was just switching rows and columns in crosstabs (I'm using SPSS) but I'm getting the same odds ratio both ways.

Also, if the confidence interval crosses 1, does this mean it not significant and thus not worth reporting?

[image]

Comment: What is the formula for the odds ratio when given a 2x2 table?  Can you put the formula for the OR by columns, & the formula for the OR by rows?

Answer (score 0):

The second command does addresses the second hypothesis, indicating that the odds for novices using validated instruments is (2/7)/(3/13) = (2*13)/(7*13) = 1.238 times that for experienced clinicians.

The odds ratio in a 2x2 table is invariant to inversion of rows and columns, as you've discovered. The first command compares the odds of users of validated instruments being novices rather than experienced to uses of non-validated instruments being novices rather than experienced.

The first hypothesis as stated says nothing about novice clinicians relative to non-novices, only novice use of instruments. It wouldn't involve an odds ratio, just an odds, which would be 2:7, and would not be supported by your data. For a formal test I would think a binomial using a one-sided alternative of the proportion being greater than .5, but since the proportion is 2/9=.222, the data come out opposite in direction from the proposed alternative, and you would not have reason to reject a null hypothesis of equal likelihood of novices using the two types of instruments.

With the small amount of data here, you don't have a lot of power to test much (notice the wide widths of the confidence intervals, for example).